# Issues with Nokogiri/Rails/zlib1g-dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu

I have ruby v.2.3.1p112 installed on my Ubuntu machine. I recently installed rails (v.5.2.1), but rails has been experiencing some problems lately related to gem non-installation, specifically with two gems and one program: nokogiri, sqlite3, and zlib1g-dev. I can't start the rails server and develop my application without these things, apparently, so I would appreciate any help getting these things installed and fixing the root issue behind the problems.

Here are the logs:

nokogiri:

It starts by saying I don't have permissions, like so:

```
foo@foo:~$ gem install nokogiri
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.5/.autotest
```

When I use "sudo".....

```
foo@foo:~$ sudo gem install nokogiri
[sudo] password for foo: 
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.5/ext/nokogiri
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20181102-6590-1t6ljhe.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.3.0
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... no
zlib is missing; necessary for building libxml2
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)2.3
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.8.5/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.8.5/gem_make.out
```

zlib1g-dev issues:

```
foo@foo:~$ sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 zlib1g-dev : Depends: zlib1g (= 1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

`mkmf.log` may explain why you can not install `nokogiri` as `sudo`, but I would check the authorization rules of this file `/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.5/.autotest` which you can not execute as normal user

you can also check for more info

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=gem+Errno%3A%3AEACCES&t=canonical&ia=qa

I use `rbenv`. Maybe if you use `rbenv` you will not experiment this issues

My gems are installed inside `/home/fabrizio/.rbenv` and not inside `/var/lib/gems/`

Comment: I checked the logs. I don't know C, so I couldn't make much sense of it. I can copy them here, if you need me to do so. I also did chmod on the directory with the gems, so I don't think permissions should have been a problem. I've tried tweaking my application's gemfile, and it seems like *every* gem won't install. I'll try to install rbenv, anything would help at this point

Comment: update: Git said I already had rbenv installed under /home/foo/.rbenv/bin.

Comment: @nameless then rbenv is not intercepting your ruby commands and it must be wrongly configured https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#how-rbenv-hooks-into-your-shell check out in details the rbenv guide and make sure all steps are working